Loose Coupling in Spring and Role of DI
I'm new to Spring and currently learning it through some paid courses. I came across the concept of loose coupling, and I understand that Spring promotes defining behavior in interfaces. However, I am wondering why it's necessary to define behavior in an interface instead of directly extending the implementation in a class?
For example, instead of:
public class Car extends PetrolEngine {
    // implementation
}

Why is it recommended to define an interface like this:
public interface Engine {
    void start();
}

public class PetrolEngine implements Engine {
    public void start() {
        // implementation
    }
}

public class Car {
    private Engine engine;

    public Car(Engine engine) {
        this.engine = engine;
    }
}


What are the advantages of using interfaces in this context, and how does this help with loose coupling in Spring?

It is not nor is it required. Loose coupling you are injecting an Engine into the Car, the car doesn't care baout the type. It could be petrol, electric or even a steam engine. You can change it without touching the Car. if you would instantiate it inside the Car constructor you would need to change it. Regarding your extension a Car isn't an engine, it is a car and as such it does make no sense to extend it. What about the body type? What about the wheels? How would you do that? Favor composition over extension.

Simple answer:
Spring DI via interface ensures that your code is:

Unit Testable
Reusable
Maintainable
Loosely coupled and highly cohesive

For example:
public interface Engine {
    void start();
}

public class PetrolEngine implements Engine {
    public void start() {
        // implementation
    }
}

public class DieselEngine implements Engine {
    public void start() {
        // implementation
    }
}

@Component
public class Car {
    
    private Engine engine;

    public Car(Engine engine) {
        this.engine = engine;
    }
}

@Configuration
public class CarConfig {

   @Bean
   public Engine engine() {
      return new PetrolEngine(); // or new DieselEngine(); based on requirement.
   }

}

When Spring will try to inject the bean into the engine instance variable present in the Car component, it will check in the IOC container and find that it has the bean with the name engine (internally referencing to PetrolEngine or DieselEngine object)
